# Loading PDF on VFR Reader from a NSURL - SIGABIT Error

Tags: objective-c, pdf

I have an URL with address of my pdf file on iPad Storage:

```
/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/78AB0683-5B3F-4AD6-83BB-236D9623574B/Library/Caches/Newsstand/953C71E3-CED3-4369-993F-9132119269EC/
```

Then I have the function to which put this address in a NSURL:

```
-(void)readIssue:(Issue *)issue {
    urlOfReadingIssue=[[issue contentURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"magazine.pdf"];
```

above this code, I have de VFR-Reader code to load this file from this URL. The original code from Reader Demo is:

```
    NSString *phrase = nil; // Document password (for unlocking most encrypted PDF files)

NSArray *pdfs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];

NSString *filePath = [pdfs lastObject]; assert(filePath != nil); // Path to last PDF file

ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:filePath password:phrase];

if (document != nil) // Must have a valid ReaderDocument object in order to proceed with things
{
    ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];

    readerViewController.delegate = self; // Set the ReaderViewController delegate to self

  if (DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH == TRUE)

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];

 #else // present in a modal view controller

    readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

    [self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];

  #endif // DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH

    [readerViewController release]; // Release the ReaderViewController
}
```

My Final Code is:

```
-(void)readIssue:(Issue *)issue {

urlOfReadingIssue=[[issue contentURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"magazine.pdf"];


NSString *phrase = nil; // Document password (for unlocking most encrypted PDF files)
    
    NSString *filePath = urlOfReadingIssue;
    
    ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:filePath
                                                           password:phrase];
    
    if (document != nil) // Must have a valid ReaderDocument object in order to proceed with things
    {
        ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
        
        readerViewController.delegate = self; // Set the ReaderViewController delegate to self
        
#if (DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH == TRUE)
        
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];
        
#else // present in a modal view controller
        
        readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        
        [self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];
        
#endif // DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH
        
        [readerViewController release]; // Release the ReaderViewController
    }
```

But when I build, I get a Thread error "SIGABIT" in AppDelegate.m on @autoreleasepool:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I can't see what's happening here. Searching on Google, I read about this error. "SIGABRT" seems to be an error from xcode.

I'm at it for hours, I appreciate if someone with more experience in VFR-Reader could best guide me about this error.

Comment: Please note that you asked 12 questions and didn't accept any answers.  This might shy away people from answering your questions.

Comment: Are you sure it's SIGABIT, not SIGABRT?

Comment: Sorry, its really SIGABRT. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSString *filePath = [urlOfReadingIssue path];
```

instead of just

```
 NSString *filePath = urlOfReadingIssue;
```

Directly assigning a `NSUrl` to `NSString` may result in this problem.

Refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put this code in the same file:

```
- (void)dismissReaderViewController:(ReaderViewController *)viewController
{
#ifdef DEBUGX
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
#endif

#if (DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH == TRUE)

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

#else // dismiss the modal view controller

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

#endif // DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
         - (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
         {
        [self seeYou:@"Complete Book-02"];
         }

       -(void)seeYou:(NSString *)filename
        {
          NSString *phrase = nil; 
         NSString *file1=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:filename ofType:@"pdf"];
    ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:file1 password:phrase];
    if (document != nil) 
    {
    ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
    readerViewController.delegate = self; 

            #if (DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH == TRUE)

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];

            #else 
    readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];

            #endif 

    [readerViewController release];     
         }

        }
```

i think this works fine.
Am also struggling for navigate different pages in pdf when user clicks the button...